# Как взять текущий путь и добавить к нему то что хочу запустить?

Tags: bat

Вот мой код

```
@echo off
SET mypath=%cd%
python  mypath/dec.py
```

Мне нужно чтобы он взял позицию откуда бат запускается и запустил dec.py

Comment: Что именно вы имеете ввиду под "откуда бат запускается"? Каталог в котором он расположен или каталог в котором введена команда на запуск?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Местоположение текущей директории в CMD/BAT можно узнать сл. образом:

```
echo %cd%
```

В вашем случае - нужно также учесть пробелы и прочую WinEPECЬ, для этого используем:

```
set x="%cd%/dec.py";
```

И вывод в данном случае будет:

```
echo %x%
```

Comment: Но питон привередлив - так что рекомендую использовать сначало cd, а после python main.py

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ,
`@Echo off
python "%~dp0dec.py"`